# Adding band to GDAL VRT dataset and converting to TIFF using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, c++, qt, geotiff-tiff, vrt

I'm trying to add a band to a TIFF dataset by converting it to a VRT format and using the `AddBand()` function, then convert it back to a TIFF to access the band and write the data. Here is an example of my code:

```
const char *formatVRT = "VRT";
const char *formatTIFF = "GTiff";
char *filenameTIFF;
char *filenameVRT;
GDALDriver pDriverTIFF, pDriverVRT;
GDALDataset pTiffDS, pVrtDS;

GDALALLRegister();

pDriverTIFF = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(formatTIFF);
pDriverVRT = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(formatVRT);

pTiffDS = pDriverTIFF->Create(filenameTIFF, cols, rows, bands, GDT_Float32, NULL);
pVrtDS = pDriverVRt->CreateCopy(filenameVRT, pTiffDS, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL);

pVrtDS->AddBand(GDT_Float32, NULL);
pTiffDS = pDriverTIFF->CreateCopy(filenameTIFF, pVrtDS, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I get the following errors:

> ERROR 1: Deleting (filenameTIFF) failed:
>
> Permission denied
>
> ERROR 1: TIFFFillStrip:Read error at scanline 25; got 0 bytes, expected 24840

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two problems. One noticed by @kyle, that the VRTDataset depends on the original, the other that the datasets needed to be closed in a specific order. Since all the datasets in this example are created in a program I was not able to use `GDALOpenShared()` as the documentation suggests, so instead the proper datasets need to be closed and removed at the proper time, then recreated. Here is the updated code:

```
const char *formatVRT = "VRT";
const char *formatTIFF = "GTiff";
char *filenameTIFF= "orignaltiff.tif";
char *filenameTempTIFF= "temptiff.tif";
char *filenameVRT = "intermediatevrt.vrt";

GDALDriver pDriverTIFF, pDriverVRT;
GDALDataset pTiffDS, pVrtDS, pTempDS;

GDALALLRegister();

pDriverTIFF = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(formatTIFF);
pDriverVRT = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(formatVRT);

pTiffDS = pDriverTIFF->Create(filenameTIFF, cols, rows, bands, GDT_Float32, NULL);
pVrtDS = pDriverVRt->CreateCopy(filenameVRT, pTiffDS, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL);

pVrtDS->AddBand(GDT_Float32, NULL);
pTempDS = pDriverTIFF->CreateCopy(filenameTempTIFF, pVrtDS, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL);

if (pTiffDS != NULL)
{
    GDALClose(pTiffDS);
    QFile::remove(filenameTiff); //this would need to be a QString not a *char
}

pTiffDS = pDriverTIFF->CreateCopy(filenameTIFF, pTempDS, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```